# software for infographics for animation

Tags: windows-8

What are good open source software to create infographics? I wanted to create some tutorial about some mathematical concepts, but, Using 3D softwares takes so much of time and computation power, Is there an open source software used for animation info graphics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Youtuber [3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw) teaches mathematical concepts using a python library named [mainim](http://www.3blue1brown.com/about/) which is on [github](https://github.com/3b1b/manim).

Comment: exactly why I asked the question. Thanks and sorry I can't upvote though.

Answer (score 0):

Open Source
[biteable.com](https://biteable.com/features/)

It’s incredibly quick and easy to use the Biteable app and turn your creative advertising ideas into great-looking digital ad videos for mobile and desktop platforms. Advertise your business or event online. Use the simple Biteable software platform to create your own custom ads from hundreds of free options or, if you’d like to save even more time, simply choose one of our pre-designed video templates.

**[Canva Infographic Maker](https://www.canva.com/create/infographics/)**

Canva's drag-and-drop interface is perfect for making infographics
Canva's a powerful and easy-to-use online tool that's suitable for all manner of design tasks, from brochures to presentations and much more besides, with a vast library of images, icons, fonts and features to choose from.

And it features a dedicated infographic maker that you can use for free, with hundreds of free design elements and fonts at your fingertips, and many more premium elements that you can buy for up to $1. You can either use it in the browser or download the Canva iPad app to design on the move.

Comment: but, it's not open source

Comment: updated answer... check this